# How to pass the AJAX responseText into a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to know how to pass the AJAX responseText into a variable? I want to use it in another part of programe. The code "document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;" can display the return string correctly, but I cannot use a variable to receive it.

```
<?PHP
$currHr=date('H')-1;
?>

<form action=""> 

<Select name="SelTime" onchange="rainSum(this.value)">
<?php
if ($currHr>0){
for ($i=$currHr; $i>=0; $i--)
{
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i.":00";
    echo " - ";
    echo $i.":59</option><br>";
}   
}else {
    for ($i=23; $i>=0; $i--)
{
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i.":00";
    echo " - ";
    echo $i.":59</option><br>";
}   
}
?>
</Select>
</form>

<p id="showData">Let AJAX change this text.</p>

<script>

function rainSum(str) 
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
  {

 if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
 {
   document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   window.x=xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "barD.php?SelTime="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}



document.write(window.x);</script>
```

Comment: Meanwhile, You can also try ajax using jquery  it passes all variables using `.serialize` I believe this question is somehow related to this that you asked, give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222160/5737654

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = rainSum("string")
function rainSum(str) 
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
  {

 if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
 {
   return xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "barD.php?SelTime="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the x variable should contain the response data  it's already containing the response since its a global variable

you dont need window.x  you just declare a variable outside the function

like this

```
var ResponseTXT='';

    function rainSum(str) 
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
      {

     if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
     {
       document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
       ResponseTXT=xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };

      xhttp.open("GET", "barD.php?SelTime="+str, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: The document.write(window.x), I just use it to do a test, is it can be use in another part of program.

Answer (score 0):

You are leading with an asynchronous state, in an asynchronous scenario you cannot assign the value to a variable in the traditional way, because, you must wait for the function to return its result, this can be done in several ways, one of them is doing async function as in the example and then consume, suscribe or call the async function and wait for its result and then use it

```
async function rainSum(str) {
    const response = await fetch(`barD.php?SelTime=${str}`);

    return await response.json();
}

// subscribe to the asynchronous function
rainSum("some string").then(response => console.log(response));
```

Some relevant links

[fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch)
[Promises, async/await](https://javascript.info/async)

Take time to understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous functions and the javascript methods to lead with these cases, it is very common to work with asynchronous functions in javascript and it is wise to familiarize yourself with the concept